# How to get user info from ASPNETDB with stored procedures

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

In my admin page i am trying to get the Users UserName, Password, and Email to repopulate controls when the admin clicks a user name from a gridview. I can't seem to get the password though as it is requiring a parameter(password answer) that i can't find.

I'm using the stored procedures of the ASPNETDB database.

```
 For Each usr As MembershipUser In Membership.GetAllUsers()
     Debug.Print(usr.Email)
     Debug.Print(usr.UserName)
     Debug.Print(usr.GetPassword("")) 'This line errors out
 Next
```

Comment: It is (This Membership Provider has not been configured to support password retrieval.)

Comment: Oh, I think I see the problem then.  You have to enable password retrieval in web.config, it's disabled by default (see my answer below for an example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to turn on the [Membership.EnablePasswordRetrieval Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.enablepasswordretrieval.aspx).  Here's the example configuration from MSDN:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
  <providers>
    <add name="SqlProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
      connectionStringName="SqlServices"
      enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
      enablePasswordReset="false"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
      passwordFormat="Encrypted"
      applicationName="MyApplication" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

**Note** that the line `enablePasswordRetrieval="true"` is what you should check for in the `membership` section of the `system.web` section of the Web.config file for your ASP.NET application.

Comment: Thank you. I am now gettng this error (Configured settings are invalid: Hashed passwords cannot be retrieved. Either set the password format to different type, or set enablePasswordRetrieval to false.) I did not use the passwordFormat = "Encrypted" because I get (You must specify a non-autogenerated machine key to store passwords in the encrypted format.) I think this is very close though.

Comment: This means you're using `passwordFormat = "Hashed"`.  You either have to use `Clear` (which is plain text) or `Encrypted` (in which case you have to set up the `decryptionKey` attribute of the `machineKey` element - see [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.passwordformat.aspx) for more info about passwordFormat)

Answer (score 1):

Documentation states that you need to pass answer to password question in order to receive password.

Comment: I entered in several test users without a question or answer. Shouldn't the null value work?